# Different User group on registration joomla 3

Tags: php, joomla3.0

I have two user groups, student and business.  On registration I want the user to select if they are a student or a business and when they click register I want them to be added to their user group automatically.

I can add the list to the registration.php and registration.xml file but how do I configure it so they get added to their specific group?

Answer (score 0):

Download and try the free Joomla extension [Usergroup Selector](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/access-a-security/site-access/frontend-access-control/25329)

I have tried it. It does what you want to do. You can configure it to allow the groups that you want. The groups show up on the registration form.